# LOTUS NOTES TRANSACTION LOG

Tags: logging, transactions

A Transactional Log in Lotus Notes Domino is simply a binary file where transactions are written. The transactions are saved in log extents that have a .TXN extension. Each log extent is 64 MB and will fill before a new extent is created or a spare one reused. Multiple log extents collectively can grow to a maximum size of 4 GB with circular logging or available disk space for archive logging.Transaction logging keeps a sequential record of every operation that occurs to data. A single transaction is a series of changes made to a database on a server. For example, a transaction might include opening a new document, adding text, and saving the document

Friends, anybody have an idea about how to read the log using Lotus notes formula/LScript or any other technic? as of now i really needed solution to read this.

Q2 ) if anyidea about how to get the databbase open/edit/save events without havng code in LN database?

Comment: STOP YELLING AT US IN YOUR TITLE

Answer (score 0):

I can answer only at the second question: It's impossible. You always need to have code in the database.
Sure you can use LS library and write the hendlers for these events there, but you still need to have the code exactly at the same database.

P.S. You can try to use OLE. Lotus can be an OLE server.
But I think that you will need the code in the database anyway...
And you will need to write an independent programm on C or VisualBasic, for example.